# get data -sqlite and android

Tags: android, sqlite

When I write

```
                     Cursor c = customersDB.rawQuery("SELECT Name, Street, Block, City  FROM "    +
                            TABLE_NAME +
                            " where Name == 'VOLKSWAGEN '", null);
```

its work goog.

but:

```
String x="ll";



                     Cursor c = customersDB.rawQuery("SELECT Name, Street, Block, City  FROM "    +
                            TABLE_NAME +
                            " where Name == "+x, null);
```

make error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap your variable in single quotes and end it with a semicolon. my advice is to use string.format so your query string would look like

```
String.format("SELECT Name, Street, Block, City FROM %1$s WHERE Name == '%2$s';", TABLE_NAME, x)
```

the other way is `"SELECT Name, Street, Block, City FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "where Name == '" + x + "';", null);`

Comment: This will fail if the string contains a quote or control characters.

Comment: obviously you should always sanitize your input strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use parameters, if possible:

```
String x="ll";
Cursor c = customersDB.rawQuery(
              "SELECT Name, Street, Block, City FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
              " WHERE Name == ?",
              new String[]{ x });
```

This avoids both formatting problems and [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.